# How can I center the standard PrintDialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, printdialog

I am printing a FlowDocument.  The standard PrintDialog appears in the upper left corner of the containing window.  I can center the dialog (using FindWindow and SetWindowPosition) if I can create an event handler that fires when the PrintDialog loads.  But I don't know how to add an event handler to the dialog. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think you can since its a OS level dialog. Question would be, whats the use case that requires the print dialog to be centered?

Comment: It's more visually pleasing.

Comment: I would hate if my PrintDialog showed up in the center. Esp. when the print button should be top/bottom left or bottom right.